# Is there a way to run a SEDE query against an older Programmers data snapshot?

Tags: support, answer-quality, data-explorer

Is it possible to get results of a particular SEDE query executed against an older data snapshot? I am interested in these in order to perform sort of retrospective study.

Query I would like to run is [Marginal short answers with links](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/102718/marginal-short-answers-with-links?AnswerScoreMax=100&AnswerScoreMin=-100&AnswerLength=200). I would like to see results of this query executed against data snapshot taken in the beginning of March / end of February, when the query was introduced. A close enough [data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207811/165773) seems to be one uploaded on March 18, 2013 here: http://www.clearbits.net/torrents/2121-mar-2013

Per my recollection, back then query has been showing about one or two (maybe three) thousands posts. Today, it shows less than 60 posts.

I would like to learn what happened to thousands posts that are not there anymore, how many was there back then, how many of these were deleted, edited, historically locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this via SEDE, so comparing data dumps is pretty much your only half-way sane option.